# Middle-button paste from vim to R

Tags: linux, r, vim, copy-paste

In vim, I use the indentLine plugin and `set list listchars=tab:\ \ ,trail:.` is activated in my vimrc, so that vim displays begin-of-line spaces as pipes "|" and end-of-line spaces as dots.
When mouse-selecting in vim and pasting into the R console (using middle click), these "special characters" are included in the R console, leading to errors.
Is there a way to select-middle-click-paste only the content rather than all the characters displayed in vim?
(note: This is under an up-to-date ubuntu linux)

Answer (score 0):

When the terminal (not Vim) performs the selection, it captures all visible screen characters (so `:set number` would cause such problems, too).

The solution is to let Vim yank the buffer contents. If you have a visual selection, that can be done via `"*y`, or `:[range]yank *`. The `*` is the mouse selection register; there's also the clipboard register `+`, cp. `:help quotestar`.

To keep using the mouse for selection, you have to change the `'mouse'` option, e.g.:

```
:set mouse=a
```

Note that all of this depends on proper clipboard support in Vim, and mouse support in the terminal.